# What does "to close over the enclosing scope/class" mean?

Tags: closures, akka

The Akka documentation is documenting dangerous variants of using `Props`:

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED within another actor:
// encourages to close over enclosing class
val props7 = Props(new MyActor)
```

Then carries on stating:

> This method is not recommended to be used within another actor because
>   it encourages to close over the enclosing scope, resulting in
>   non-serializable Props and possibly race conditions (breaking the
>   actor encapsulation).

Could someone please explain the meaning of "closing over the enclosing scope"? Been looking all over and found nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to see in this example, that the `new Actor` is passed in as a so called "by name" parameter. Think of it as if it is turned into a function of type  `() => Actor`. This function will be called every time the actor will be (re)created by it's supervisor during a restart.

The problem is that this function is a "closure" (very easy to Google ;)), which means it captures and remembers everything in the surrounding scope that it needs (sometimes, but very rarely referred to as "stack ripping"). E.g `val f = (a: Int) => a + x`. Where does the `x` come from? It comes from the surrounding scope. The function litetal, assigned to `f` is called an "open term". At runtime the function literal becomes a function value (that's a fancy way of saying "object"), which when executed **closes the open term**, while capturing everything in the surrounding scope. That's where the name "closure" comes from.

Closures are very very useful, but you have to be careful what you close over. Sometimes `x` is a `def` or god forbid a `var`, which leads to unpredictable results for `f`, because you don't have control over the time when `f` will be called/executed. Try it out!

Two very common anti paterns in Akka are/were:

1. Closing over (the outer) `this` reference when creating an Actor
   from an inner class.
2. Closing over `def sender` when responding to
       a message with a future.

I gave you a bunch of fancy terms to Google on purpose, btw ;)

Cheers and happy coding

Comment: Thanks. Rich explanation.

Answer (score 8):

As a supplement to @agilesteel's fine answer, some references:

Explains what closures are: *Programming in Scala*, 8.7, Closures

Explains why closures can cause serialization problems: [SIP-21 - Spores](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/spores.html#serialization)

And here is a code example of creating a Props object that is not serializable because of closing over a non-serializable object, based on the example in SIP-21:

```
case class Helper(name: String)

object MyNonserializableObject {

    val helper = Helper("the helper")

    val props7 = Props(new MyActor(helper))
}
```

Even though `helper` itself is serializable, the "new MyActor(helper)" is passed by name and so captures `this.helper`, and `this` is not serializable.

You can see that the actor parameter is passed by name from the signature of the `Props` `apply` method where there is a ⇒ in the `creator` parameter:

```
def apply[T <: Actor](creator: ⇒ T)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Props
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.