# Is creating a props object by calling a constructor manually safe and recommended?

Tags: scala, akka-actor

I am trying to get fammiliar with Akka *actors* and I cannot get my head around these two issues:
First as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26903051/2890080) closures can cause serialization problems. The example below contains a Props object that is not serializable because it closes over a non-serializable object:

```
case class Helper(name: String)

object MyNonserializableObject {

   val helper = Helper("the helper")

   val props7 = Props(new MyActor(helper))
}
```

So it is suggested not to create an Actor like this. The answer above is related to Akka docs [dangerous variants](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#dangerous-variants).
On the other hand when we are dealing with *value classes as constructor arguments* Akka docs [recommends](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#value-classes-as-constructor-arguments) creating props by calling the constructor manually that `props3` on the code below is an example of:

```
class Argument(val value: String) extends AnyVal

class ValueClassActor(arg: Argument) extends Actor {
  def receive = { case _ => () }
}

object ValueClassActor {
  def props1(arg: Argument) = Props(classOf[ValueClassActor], arg) // fails at runtime
  def props2(arg: Argument) = Props(classOf[ValueClassActor], arg.value) // ok
  def props3(arg: Argument) = Props(new ValueClassActor(arg)) // ok
}
```

These two concepts appear paradoxical to me. 
By the way because of my rank I coud not create this question as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to understand if you know how JVM works. If you instantiate object using `classOf[ValueClassActor]` and list of args, JVM has to extract `Constructor` from `Class` object and then instantiate object using Java reflection API.

Meanwhile if you take a look what `AnyVal`s are, you'll see that class taking `AnyVal`

```
class Argument(val value: String) extends AnyVal

class ValueClassActor(arg: Argument)
```

compiles to:

```
Compiled from "test.scala"
public class ValueClassActor {
  public ValueClassActor(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #14                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0       5     0  this   LValueClassActor;
          0       5     1   arg   Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

so `Argument` type exists only at compile time (well, mostly, [sometimes Scala instantiates it](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#when-allocation-is-necessary)) and if you want to call the constructor that JVM actually sees, you need to pass `String` isntead of `Argument`. That's why you have this behavior you aboserve:

```
  def props1(arg: Argument) = Props(classOf[ValueClassActor], arg) // fails at runtime
  def props2(arg: Argument) = Props(classOf[ValueClassActor], arg.value) // ok
```

To avoid dealing with this issue, you can use [`Props` creator](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/Props$.html#apply%5BT%3C:akka.actor.Actor%5D(creator:=%3ET)(implicitevidence$2:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BT%5D):akka.actor.Props) which doesn't rely on runtime reflection:

```
def apply[T <: Actor](creator: => T)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): Props
```

Is it dangerous? Documentations says:

> CAVEAT: Required mailbox type cannot be detected when using anonymous mixin composition when creating the instance. For example, the following will not detect the need for DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics as defined in Stash:
>
> `'Props(new Actor with Stash { ... })`
>
> Instead you must create a named class that mixin the trait, e.g. class MyActor extends Actor with Stash.

which means that as long as you will simply use named class and just provide arguments to it without any minxins on anonymous subclasses you remove one potential issue. To avoid the issue of having closure, you can do what is [exactly said in documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#recommended-practices) and create that `Prop` construction in companion object.

Problem is that when you try to create `Prop` it could be serialized if you send it through the internet to another part of your application if you had e.g. Akka Cluster. And if you try to serialize a function (here: anonymous `Function` that is `new ValueClassActor(arg)), it would fetch its whole closure if you tried to serialize it. Because of how Java works this function would have a pointer to the parent object within which it was created.

If you have

```
class Foo(s: => String)

object Foo {
  def hello: Foo = new Foo("test") // "test" is by-name so it has closure
}
```

and you take a look at generated bytecode you'll see that there is

```
Compiled from "foo.scala"
public class Foo {
  public static Foo hello();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #16                 // Field Foo$.MODULE$:LFoo$;
       3: invokevirtual #18                 // Method Foo$.hello:()LFoo;
       6: areturn

  public Foo(scala.Function0<java.lang.String>);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #25                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3: 0
      line 1: 4
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0       5     0  this   LFoo;
          0       5     1     s   Lscala/Function0;
}
```

and

```
Compiled from "foo.scala"
public final class Foo$ {
  public static final Foo$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Foo$
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #17                 // Method "<init>":()V
       7: putstatic     #19                 // Field MODULE$:LFoo$;
      10: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3: 0

  public Foo hello();
    Code:
       0: new           #23                 // class Foo
       3: dup
       4: invokedynamic #44,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:apply:()Lscala/Function0;
       9: invokespecial #47                 // Method Foo."<init>":(Lscala/Function0;)V
      12: areturn
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0      13     0  this   LFoo$;

  public static final java.lang.String $anonfun$hello$1();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #50                 // String test
       2: areturn
    LineNumberTable:
      line 4: 0
}
```

Which means that:

- when you call `Foo.hello` and create a lambda `new Foo("test")` the closure of that function is only the companion object instance
- companion object is implementing `Serializable`
- therefore it fulfills requirement that function's closure is serializable

`object MyNonserializableObject` is kind of shortcut in explanation as out of the box `object`s **are** serializable and you would have to do something weird with them to make them non-serializable. E.g. if you did

```
trait Bar {

  object Baz {
    def hello: Foo = new Foo("test")  // "test" is by-name so it has closure
  }
}
```

closure would hold reference to `Baz`, which would hold reference to `Bar` and if whatever extends `Bar` was not serializable, so wouldn't be the closure. But if you will generate your lambda inside an `object` which is top-level (isn't nested in some other class, etc), then your closure could only depend on something that is serializable (because `object` on their own have empty constructors and implement `Serializable` interface), and so be serializable on its own.

Same principle works when it comes to `Props` and by-name params. If you create a `Prop` using by-name param within a companion object that is top level (or is otherwise guaranteed to be serializable) then the closure will be serializable as well and the usage will be safe. Just like docs recommendation says.

So long story short:

```
class ValueClassActor(arg: Argument) extends Actor {
  def receive = { case _ => () }
}

object ValueClassActor {
  def props(arg: Argument) = Props(new ValueClassActor(arg))
}
```

is safe.

Comment: thanks for your clarification, but still I cannot get what's the difference between the safe example and props7 on my first example that is unsafe.

Comment: is this explanation better?

Comment: yes thanks a lot! so the problem is Helper on the example is case class and related to some kind of trait and therefore it makes Props non-serializable is that it?

Comment: The code from the example _is_ serializable, so I can only assume that this is a _placeholder_ for something that wouldn't be in a real project.

Comment: so maybe we should comment or flag the related post?

Comment: Not really, from the context it is rather clear (at least to me) that author wrote a pseudocode for illustration and not a reproducible example.